# map (vs) unordered_map with pair as key

Tags: c++, c++14, unordered-map

This produces compiler error

```
unordered_map<pair<int,int>,int> umap;
```

I understand that a hash function must be provided for it to work.

But

```
map<pair<int,int>,int> omap;
```

works perfectly without any hash function.

Why is that so?

Comment: What compiler error is it producing?

Comment: https://ideone.com/lgS58Z

Answer (score 3):

[std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) does not use a hash function. Rather, its "keys are sorted by using the comparison function..." where "search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity.". Lookup is done by traversing a search tree rather than via hashing.